# htaccess-rewrite-rule for more than one parameter

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting, rule

I use the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)? index.php?action=$1
```

for rewriting

> www.mysite.com/123

to

> www.mysite.com/index.php?action=123

This needs to remain like this, but there are cases where I also need to rewrite

> www.mysite.com/123/abc

to

> www.mysite.com/index.php?action=123&example=abc

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&example=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: that seems to work, thank you, but could you explain why you changed my line to your new (the last in your post)?

Comment: Sure I will add some explanation to my answer as soon as I am close to my computer. Also if it worked can you mark it as accepted.

Comment: Just got back. Your rule had 2 issues: 1. Not using `L` flag (to mark end of rule) and 2. Combining 2 rules into 1 isn't a good idea otherwise you might get `example` parameter as null sometimes.

Comment: It's working perfect now, thank you! My "issue" had nothing to do with your rule directly, but my CSS, JS and IMG-links were all relative because I only had one "sub-directory" (which the htaccess-rule turns to parameters) before that change ;)