# .htaccess rewrite rule for several parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have found some usefull links but I can't figure out why isn't working.
Current url:

```
http://localhost/noyk/clients/clients.php?name=StackOverflow&category=technology
```

The final url I would like it to be:

```
http://localhost/noyk/clients/StackOverflow/technology
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753370/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-more-than-one-parameter) topic, and I've tried to adapt.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you guys tell me that this should work it does not.

When I type in the url `http://localhost/noyk/clients/StackOverflow` I receive the default XAMPP page error:

```
The requested URL /noyk/clients/StackOverFlow was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite in the main config file (and restarted apache?). Where is .htaccess located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your .htaccess file is in your site root? If so, either move to /noyk/clients/ or edit as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^noyk/clients/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1&category=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^noyk/clients/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```